# value cannot be null on da.fill(dt)

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, combobox

```
 sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblOfficeEquipmentCategory", sqlconn)
    Dim dt As DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmbCategory.DataSource = dt
    cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CAT_ID"
    cmbCategory.ValueMember = "CAT_NAME"
    sqlconn.Close()
```

returning an error pointing to da.fill(dt)

Run-time exception thrown : System.ArgumentNullException - Value cannot be null.

Comment: Where is your commandbuilder?

Comment: sir i know how to make a command builder but not combined to a dataadapter.. this is my code

 myCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from tblOfficeEquipmentCategory", sqlconn)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Ok, cmbcategory is datagridview or combobox? If for feel with dataadapter, looks like it dont need EXECUTENONQUERY. Cause at my own project that fill to my datagridview, i even not use execute.(Cause i just use connection to EXCEL, but if SQL, access or database, looks like it need

Comment: its a combobox sir, i use sql and vb.net  any suggestions sir?

Comment: Ok,, not just your VALUEMEMBER error isn't it? Check that your upper and lower case is correct or not. It's case sensitive too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblOfficeEquipmentCategory", sqlconn)
    Dim dt As NEW DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
```

Without NEW, your data don't have place to store cause you just get variable but don't get the form.

**Update**

Beside that, i just have found that your data won't show up and will got error about execute.

Like `oledbcommand.executenonquery()` before `sqlconn.close`, but i didn't see your command code.

```
sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblOfficeEquipmentCategory", sqlconn)
    Dim dt As DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmbCategory.DataSource = dt
    cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CAT_ID"
    cmbCategory.ValueMember = "CAT_NAME"
oledbcommand.executenonquery()<<<< HERE
    sqlconn.Close()
```

Comment: thank you sir, but now im having a problem

 cmbCategory.ValueMember = "CAT_NAME"

saying Could not bind to the new value member.

Comment: uPDATE your question please, Or take me to your new question link

Answer (score 2):

you should assign your `DataTable` with `new` keyword :

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblOfficeEquipmentCategory", sqlconn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmbCategory.DataSource = dt
    cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CAT_NAME"
    cmbCategory.ValueMember = "CAT_ID"
    sqlconn.Close()
```

its working now thanks for the answers, i just re assigned the displaymember and valuemember

its not returning cannot bind to value member error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805148/filtering-the-second-combobox-based-on-index-on-the-first-combobox Here is your link