# filtering the second combobox based on index on the first combobox

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, combobox

```
   Public Sub FiltercmbSubCategory()
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim sqlcommand As SqlCommand

    sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentSubCategory WHERE SUBCAT_ID = '" & cmbCategory.Text & "'", sqlconn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmbCategory.DataSource = dt
    cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "SUBCAT_Name"
    cmbCategory.ValueMember = "SUBCAT_ID"
    sqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```

when i put this code on the form load event the data on the first combo box dissappears
also when i put this code on the index_changed of the first combobox

but when i commented this code it displays the records again in combobox 1

i need to filter the SUB_CATEGORY_COMBO_BOX  based on the CATEGORY_COMBOBOX

Comment: You just want to show it in combobox isn't it?

Comment: do you have two dropdowns or have single?

Comment: @KenClark its a two dropdown comboboxes

Comment: @Never_Mind i already know how to populate the category combo dropdown box... so when i choose COM it will display on subcategory combo dropdown box the corresponding subcategories

Answer (score 1):

Bind your first combobox inside:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //  Bind combobox1 code here;
}
```

Now, on selectedindexchange call the code for binding subcategory combo.

Also, have look on your code again:

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentSubCategory WHERE SUBCAT_ID = '" & cmbCategory.Text & "'", sqlconn)
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
cmbCategory.DataSource = dt
cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "SUBCAT_Name"
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "SUBCAT_ID"
```

In this code you are passing `cmbCategory.Text` as paramater for binding same dropdown `cmbCategory`. I think you have missed your second dropdown here. May be I am not correct but, it seems like that.

Comment: is it?  as i understand my select and where sql syntax, it will display the data from Subcategory table where subcatid  is equal to the key category combobox. im confused now

Comment: look at your select code you are passing cmbCategory.Text as parameter right? and below that you are binding the same dropdown again which is cmbCategory but in my point of view it should be the subcategory dropdown..

Comment: another main thing is that you should bind your first dropdown inside if (!Page.IsPostBack) block to not to lose current value.

Comment: i see! your right my datasource is still cmbCategory i didnt notice it at first..

i dont know about binding the combobox.. any suggestion sir?

its cmbCategory.text

Comment: Please paste your page load code where you are binding first dropdown and paste the name of second dropdown. Update your answer with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Is subcat_id a string or integer? If its integer drop the single quotes in your where clause.

Also to me it seems you are filling the same combobox that you select from with data, and not the sub box ?

```
    cmbCategory[SUB?].DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    End Sub
```

I think is like this, what you want is, what you choose on 1combobox, it will display to combobox2 ?is like that?

**UPDATE**

```
     Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 

sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Column_name FROM tblOfficeEquipmentSubCategory 
WHERE column_name_ = '" % & combobox1.selecteditem & % "'", sqlconn)
   From here >>> Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    da1.Fill(dt)
    cmbsubCategory.DataSource = dt1
    cmbsubCategory.DisplayMember = "SUBCAT_Name"
    cmbsubCategory.ValueMember = "SUBCAT_ID"
    sqlconn.Close()
                    End Sub <<< till here, you need to change yourself
```

Comment: somewhat like that sir, ill clarify it more better,

category combo box data is
1. computer
2. printer

subcategory combobox data is
1.dell computer, hp computer, epson printer, hp printer

so when i choose computer on category combo box,,
it will not show the epson printer and hp printer only the
dell computer and hp computer

Comment: sir cannot add items  when the datasource or databinding is set

Comment: Some like that, i have reedit again. actually your problem is what i would meet after several days. But i think this could work actually. Beside that, you still need primary key and foreign key in your database to link it and made it more simple

Comment: yes sir, its linked using a foreign and primary key ill give it a try sir

Comment: returns error on %  i think its something like '%' when using wildcard like for search sql syntax

Answer (score 0):

You have used same object cmbCategory for both  SUB_CATEGORY_COMBO_BOX based on the CATEGORY_COMBOBOX

**You should use cmbSubCategory for SUB_CATEGORY_COMBO_BOX   and cmbCategory for CATEGORY_COMBOBOX**

```
 Public Sub FiltercmbSubCategory()
            Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
            "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

            Dim sqlcommand As SqlCommand

            sqlconn.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentSubCategory WHERE SUBCAT_ID = '" & cmbCategory.Text & "'", sqlconn)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            cmbSubCategory.DataSource = dt
            cmbSubCategory.DisplayMember = "SUBCAT_Name"
            cmbSubCategory.ValueMember = "SUBCAT_ID"
            cmbSubCategory.databind();
            sqlconn.Close()
        End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes sir, im sorry ive written  SUB_CATEGORY_COMBO_BOX  and  CATEGORY_COMBOBOX

but my code is really cmbCategory and cmbSubCategory

Comment: @ivandinglasan: as per your code you have passed the cmbCategory.text as paramater to the select query and also you have binded  the datasource to same cmbCategory. Thats the problem. please look the code that with modification .

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SUBCAT_ID FROM tblOfficeEquipmentSubCategory WHERE CAT_ID = '" & cmbCategory.Text & "'", sqlconn)
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmbSubCategory.DataSource = dt
    cmbSubCategory.DisplayMember = "SUBCAT_Name"
    cmbSubCategory.ValueMember = "SUBCAT_ID"
    sqlconn.Close()
```

got the correct answer thanks everyone